Changing the text of a span element with no Id
I am very new to this so please bear with me.
I'm trying to change the inner HTML of this span on page load:
<span translate="my_team_tab" class="ng-scope">My Team</span>

I would like to change the "My Team" text to "My Event". I've been looking for hours and nothing seems to be working. Maybe it's not possible? Like I said, I'm new and would not know otherwise.
I haven't been able to try anything because almost all solutions mention using an Id and there is no Id assigned to this element. This code is hardcoded into the system I'm working in so I can't change the HTML itself.

Can't you change the HTML source code?

From what you posted, it is not possible for anybody to give you advice because there is not enough context. There are ways of using the structure of the DOM to operate from elements that are identified and navigate through the page structure to locate what you want to change. However, it would be necessary to know more about your document structure, and we don't.

You can try to find the element by the attribute name translate and its value, but I dont see how anyone can help you with this without more context

You can do this with CSS if absolutely necessary.


span[translate="my_team_tab"] {
  font-size: 0;
}

span[translate="my_team_tab"]:after {
  content: "My Event";
  font-size: initial;
}
<span translate="my_team_tab" class="ng-scope">My Team</span>




But when you select the text, you don't see the selection. And when you paste what you have selected, you get "My Team".

You didn't state that as a requirement. If this is the case you need to [edit] the question.

This actually worked perfectly for me and was very simple. Thank you!

This will fix the Original Poster particular case only:


document.addEventListener('readystatechange', readyEvent => {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    const allSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

    for (const span of allSpans) {
      if (span.textContent == 'My Team') {
        span.textContent = 'My Event';

        // Or...
        // span.innerHTML = '...';
      }
    }
  }
});
<div>
  "<code><span>My Team</span></code>"
  <span>was "<code>My Team</code>".</span>
</div>




Just FYI if you use the DOMContentLoaded event instead of readystatechange then you can avoid the text update being visible as the page renders

You can select the element by Specific Tag Value:
const item = document.querySelector('[translate="my_team_tab"]');
item.innerText = 'Hello World!';


First, I defined a constant for language, you may infer the language differently. Then, I defined a translateMap with keys representing the values of translate and values representing a map of languages and their value in the given language.
Finally, I search for all translatable, that is, elements having a translate attribute, loop them and if the given element has a translation in the given language, then setting innerText to the translation:


const language = "en";
const translateMap = {
    my_team_tab: {
        en: "My Event"
    }
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    for (let translatable of document.querySelectorAll("[translate]")) {
        if (translateMap[translatable.getAttribute("translate")][language]) {
            translatable.innerText = translateMap[translatable.getAttribute("translate")][language];
        }
    }
});
<span translate="my_team_tab" class="ng-scope">My Team</span>




Typically, you can change the content using javascript.
You said:

I'm trying to change the inner HTML of this span... on page load.

Assuming you're doing it using javascript it should look something like:
window.onload = function() {
  // This will get all the spans in the page!
  // If the text is exactly present in more than one span
  // it will be replaced in all occurrences!
  let spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for( let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
    if(spans[i] && spans[i].innerText == "My Team" ){
      spans[i].innerText = "My Event";
    }
  }
};

However if this is something that you should do for multiple spans with different texts, it could be helpful to write a generic function for it.
